# Android Studio build failed (java compiler errors)

Tags: java, android, build

I just upgraded my Android Studio and now I am getting these errors for build:

Java compiler:

```
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
failed linking references.
```

The Error screenshoot:

[image]

I cannot see the style file the compiler complains about & another error to go is that it does not identify the R file. I have tried clean & rebuild, invalidate and restart.

I had AS 3.0.1 and it updated to 3.1.2. Gradle version 4.4

Comment: Provide your build.gradle file

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

**Step 1:** Safely delete the `build` folder from app directory.
**Step 2:** In Android Studio, `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`
**Step 3:** `Build -> Clean Project` Then `Build -> Rebuild Project`.

so `build` folder will be regenerated and hope so error is gone.

If not solve then your issue in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to try to update the google support dependencies in gradle file